# How to send only the properties of SKSpritenode through GameCenter

Tags: sprite-kit, game-center, skspritenode, nskeyedarchiver, sknode

Using NSKeyedArchiver and UnArchiver, I am sending SKSpriteNode through GameCenter but I would like to reduce the size of the message by reducing the data sent.  My idea for doing this is to only send SKSpriteNodes' properties and exclude the bitmap.  Any way I can achieve this?  Much appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you are sending the bitmap?  should just be sending a pointer to SKTexture, which if you are using an atlas, is a shared pointer

Comment: anyway subclass your sprite, override the `required init(coder:)` and encoder, and do not call `super.init(coder:)` just call `super(init)`, and save whatever properties you need to save,  the rest you will need to find a way to generate again obviously